# Regex that exclude all except some words

Tags: c#, regex

I though that filtering a string like :
`"Hello <strong>plip</strong> plop"`
to obtain
`"plip plop"`, that is, excluding all words except 'plip' and 'plop' would be easy with this C# line:
`new Regex("[^(plip)(plop)]").Replace(inputString,"")`. 
Unfortunalty, the excluding brackets `[^]` seem to not accept exclusion words, as it keeps each letters contained in 'plip' and 'plop' (the result is `"llooplipoplop"`).

Is there a way to achieve this in a single regex/line, or is it necessary to loop other all matches of plip and plop, then concat them?

Comment: `[^(plip)(plop)]` doesn't do what you think it does, it is the same as `[^()plio]` (i.e. matches any character except those six). This indeed skips all the characters in `plip` and `plop`, but also the `l`s and `o` in `hello`, and the `o` in `strong`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, it is much easier to write a regex that matches what you do want than one that matches all the stuff you don't want.

In this case you want to "exclude all words except `plip` and `plop`", but why not just include only `plip` and `plop` instead?

```
var input = "Hello <strong>plip</strong> plop";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, "plip|plop");
var result = string.Join("", matches.Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value));

Console.Out.WriteLine(result); // prints "plipplop"
```

Of course since you asked for a one-liner, you could do everything without the temp variables (and good luck to the next guy reading the code!):

```
var result = string.Join("", Regex.Matches("Hello <strong>plip</strong> plop", "plip|plop").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value));
```

Also, assuming you actual word list is more complicated than `plip` and `plop`, you can do something like `var pattern = string.Join("|", words);` to construct the pattern.

Comment: Thanks, I finally have adopted this way of doing, as this regex is clearer and more easy to maintain.

Answer (score 3):

hope this works

```
(?<=(\bplip\b|\bplop\b|^)).*?(?=(\bplip\b|\bplop\b|$))
```

You should set the `singleline` mode for the above regex to work

works [here](http://regexhero.net/tester/)

Comment: Thanks for this pure regex proposal! Too bad the "(\bplip\b|\bplop\b|$)" group has to be duplicated.